# How to fire places_changed on google map without enter manually

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autofill

I want to fill the input of google map as per user address and change the whole map on the basis of that.

I try to trigger input on basis of enter but it won't worked
I also try to trigger `places_changed` but map doesn't changed

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <button>trigger</button>
    <input id="textbox" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#pac-input" ).val("268 Pitt Street, Waterloo, New South Wales, Australia");

        $('button').click(function(){
          debugger
          var e = $.Event("keypress");
          e.keyCode = 13; // # Some key code value
          $('#pac-input').focus();
          $('#pac-input').trigger(e);
        });


        $('#pac-input').keypress(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == '13') {
            /*google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox, 'place_changed');*/

            $('#pac-input').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {which: 13}));

            return false;
          }
        });
      });

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHLIhQaziL6s-7VIsiSvgu2nDolUxWAsc&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
            async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using the SearchBox if it is not for user input?

Comment: i will show map on modal after trigger and if the user want to change its location then he/she can change from searchBox

Comment: So why can't you initial the map with this address in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to trigger **keydown** event over the input element using google maps event:

```
var input = $("#pac-input").get(0);
google.maps.event.trigger(input, "focus");
google.maps.event.trigger(input, "keydown", {
   keyCode: 13
});
```

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sju1xws0/